# Table outline and horizontal line do not match

Tags: tables, mathjax

Strangely, it works well on other sites, but on my site, the outline is broken.
There seems to be no problem with the code, what is the problem?

```
  \begin{array}{|l|l|} 
  \hline   & A \\ 
  \hline X & 1 \\ 
  \hline Y & 3333 \\ 
  \hline
  \end{array}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello! If you have a code,please provide it as a MWE, otherwise nobody can tell you thats wrong with it. https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Though related, this site is *not* for MathJax questions.